# In Firemonkey, how to program "Show All" in OS X application menu?

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

The OS X application menu typically includes "Show All".

Unlike "Hide" and "Hide Others", there is not a standard action for "Show All". How is it programmed in Firemonkey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `NSApplication.unhideAllApplications` function.

```
uses Macapi.AppKit;

procedure TForm1.ShowAllClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TNSApplication.Wrap(TNSApplication.OCClass.sharedApplication).unhideAllApplications(nil);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! I was troubled at first by a message "cannot resolve unit name macapi.appkit" but this turned out to be just the buggy IDE and the program actually builds and runs despite the error message.